# Linux C sockets - recvmsg - getting source ifindex

Tags: c, linux, sockets, recvmmsg

I'm opening a RAW socket in Linux and reading all messages.

```
recvmsg(mysock, &msg, 0);
```

I'm traversing on all cmsg on that msg buffer and I get only one.

```
    for (c = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg); c; c = CMSG_NXTHDR(&msg, c)) {
```

How can I extract the ifindex on which it received on ?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. I had to set the IP_PKTINFO flag first:

```cpp
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_PKTINFO, &hold, sizeof(hold));
```